# matplotlib, colormap with transparency looks different in colorbar and imshow

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I would like to use a custom colormap with varying alpha values. However, when adding a colorbar the colors look different. I believe that the example attached below shows this quite clearly: The colors in the colorbar pass though reddish colors (as expected), whereas the data in the figure seems to be more greyish.

How can I resolve this?
I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something trivial...

Versions: matplotlib: 1.4.3, python: 2.7.3

Minimal(-ish) example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pyhelpers.checker_hatch import hatch_axes


# build up some testing data
xx,_ = np.mgrid[0:10,0:10]

# set up a linear colormap which is red and only changes alpha
# (1,0,0,1) --> (1,0,0,0) 
colors = [(1,0,0,i) for i in np.linspace(1,0,3)]
cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', colors, N=10)

# confirm that the colormap looks like we want it to look
print("- colors --------")
map(print, colors)
for k,v in cmap._segmentdata.iteritems():
    print("-", k, "---------")
    map(print, v)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# add a hatched background rectangle to aid the visualization of transparency
r = plt.Rectangle((-0.5, -0,5), 10, 10, fc='w', ec='b', hatch='/', zorder=-10)
ax.add_patch(r)

# plot the data
im = plt.imshow(xx, cmap=cmap, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest')

# build a colorbar, hatch the background patch and remove the solids edgecolors
cb = plt.colorbar(im)
cb.patch.set_hatch('/')
cb.patch.set_ec('b')
cb.solids.set_edgecolors((0,0,0,0))

plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

Output:

> ```
> - colors --------
> (1, 0, 0, 1.0)
> (1, 0, 0, 0.5)
> (1, 0, 0, 0.0)
> - blue ---------
> (0.0, 0, 0)
> (0.5, 0, 0)
> (1.0, 0, 0)
> - alpha ---------
> (0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
> (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
> (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
> - green ---------
> (0.0, 0, 0)
> (0.5, 0, 0)
> (1.0, 0, 0)
> - red ---------
> (0.0, 1, 1)
> (0.5, 1, 1)
> (1.0, 1, 1)
> ```

Figure:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

I should have looked at the issues on github first:
It seems that this is related to the alpha handling of `imshow`:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3343

Comment: This may be to do with me not being very good with colours, but they look the same to me?

Comment: I agree, the colours are definitely different (more grey on the `imshow`, as you said). I don't know why, but interestingly if you use `pcolormesh` instead of `imshow`, the colours match the `colorbar`

Comment: @areuexperienced I'm quite sure that they are different. You can check with any image editing software.... @tom: interesting observation, thanks! However, I can't switch to `pcolormesh`, since I want to use the interpolation functionality of `imshow` in my real plot.

Comment: Yeah, didn't think it was a solution, but hoped it might point to the reason for the difference. Good luck!