# Discretized colormap for step function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've to plot a step function `f = 1 or 0` depending on 2 variables `x` and `y`, such that:

0 -> transparent

1 -> green

I'd like to keep using the `pcolor(x, y, f, cmap)` module since I'm already using a `pcolor` module to plot a different set of data, with a different colormap.

How can I get the step function plot and how can I superpose it (so I need transparent color) over the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a colormap to go from green to transparent (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828445/matplotlib-colormap-with-transparency-looks-different-in-colorbar-and-imshow)) and then just overlay this over your current pcolor.

As a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def heaviside(x):
    return .5 * (np.sign(x) + 1)

# set up a linear colormap which is green and only changes alpha
# (0,1,0,green_alpha) --> (0,1,0,0) 
green_alpha = 0.1
colors = [(0,1,0,i) for i in np.linspace(green_alpha,0,2)]
gtrans = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', colors, N=2)

#Generate dummy data from 
#http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html
dx, dy = 0.15, 0.05
y, x = np.mgrid[slice(-3, 3 + dy, dy),
                slice(-3, 3 + dx, dx)]
z = (1 - x / 2. + x ** 5 + y ** 3) * np.exp(-x ** 2 - y ** 2)
z = z[:-1, :-1]

#Plot first colormap
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.pcolor(x, y, z, cmap='RdYlBu_r')


#Overlay rectangle using heaviside and transparency
xmin = -2.; xmax = 2.
ymin = -2.; ymax = 2.
#2D product of Heavisides defines a square
z = ( (heaviside(x+xmin) - heaviside(x+xmax))
     *(heaviside(y+ymin) - heaviside(y+ymax)))
ax.pcolor(x, y, z, cmap=gtrans)

plt.show()
```

Which looks like this,
[image]