# Is it possible to use basemap in python to create a opaque (see-through) map?

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps, matplotlib-basemap

Is it possible to use Python basemap (matplotlib) to plot a map where the fill colours are see through (translucent)? I'm constructing a heat map of Australia by suburb and I eventually intend to overlay this with a google maps image. Therefore, I'd like the fill colours to be translucent. My code is pretty long (250 lines) so it's probably best to not post all of it. Will appreciate any advice. Most likely, it involves setting colormap's alpha value to something between 0 and 1. I am using Python's matplotlib basemap (if that helps). I've also used code from this website (it may help you to understand what i am doing): http://brandonrose.org/pythonmap

```
# Convenience functions for working with color ramps and bars
def colorbar_index(ncolors, cmap, labels=None, **kwargs):
"""
This is a convenience function to stop you making off-by-one errors
Takes a standard colour ramp, and discretizes it,
then draws a colour bar with correctly aligned labels
"""
cmap = cmap_discretize(cmap, ncolors)
mappable = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap)
mappable.set_array([])
mappable.set_clim(-0.5, ncolors + 0.5)
colorbar = plt.colorbar(mappable, **kwargs)
colorbar.set_ticks(np.linspace(0, ncolors, ncolors))
colorbar.set_ticklabels(range(ncolors))
#colorbar.set_alpha(0.5)
if labels:
    colorbar.set_ticklabels(labels)
return colorbar


def cmap_discretize(cmap, N):
"""
Return a discrete colormap from the continuous colormap cmap.

    cmap: colormap instance, eg. cm.jet.
    N: number of colors.

Example
    x = resize(arange(100), (5,100))
    djet = cmap_discretize(cm.jet, 5)
    imshow(x, cmap=djet)

"""
if type(cmap) == str:
    cmap = get_cmap(cmap)
colors_i = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0, 1., N), (0., 0., 0., 0.)))
colors_rgba = cmap(colors_i)
indices = np.linspace(0, 1., N + 1)
cdict = {}
for ki, key in enumerate(('red', 'green', 'blue')):
    cdict[key] = [(indices[i], colors_rgba[i - 1, ki], colors_rgba[i, ki]) for i in xrange(N + 1)]
return matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap(cmap.name + "_%d" % N, cdict, 1024)
```

Comment: You could try looking at the online manual for creating **transparent** maps. (Opaque means the opposite of see-through). Some hints might be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828445/matplotlib-colormap-with-transparency-looks-different-in-colorbar-and-imshow

Comment: thanks - ill fix my usage of opaque